# How to remove all tags including content in PHP apart from certain specified ones?

Tags: php, html, regex, tags

I have a string in PHP which contains a full HTML document (including `<script>`, `<header>`, `<footer>`, etc tags).

How could I remove all of these tags and their content apart from a certain few?

I would like to keep the `<p>`, `<b>`, `<img>`, `<h2>` and `<em>` tags along with the content inside of those tags. Everything else should be removed.

I am not really sure how to tackle this and cannot find any problems/solutions online that are similar to mine.

```
<p>Hello <b>this</b></p> is an <span>example</span>
```

The example above should become:

```
<p>Hello <b>this</b></p>
```

The code should remove all tags and content that aren't contained in an array of specified tags to keep.

Comment: Maybe [`strip_tags()`](http://php.net/strip_tags) could helps you.

Comment: @Syscall I've looked into that but that does not remove the content in between tags.

Answer (score 1):

This is a peasant way but you could `preg_replace` every tag you want at a time:

```
$text = "<header>This is header</header><body><p>This is paragraph</p></body>";
$text = preg_replace("/<header(.*)<\/header>/iUs", "", $text);
```

You can use `preg_replace` to `<script>`, `<footer>`, etc

Answer (score 0):

What you want is far more complex than a simple DoM manipulation. Because you need to delete part of innerHtml for specified tags. What you can do is getting all your important element by tagName (getElementByTagName) and look at the innerHtml. But what do you expect for the whole HTML ?

Here is a sample code that concat innerHtml for specified tags you want to keep. But you need first to identify your HTML div using Id or Class. Once you are done :

```
var myHtml = document.getElementById('myHtml');

var tagsToKeep = ["p", "h1"...];
var newHtml = ""

tagsToKeep.forEach((tag)=> var tagHtml = myHtml.getElementByTagName(tag);

tagHtml.forEach((element) => { newHtml += element.innerHTML + "\n" });
});
```